# User Model always return null Laravel 5.1.24

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

[Here is the output when i used tinker in artisan to query User Model and Team Model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsdMv.png)

As shown in the images above User Model always return null when in fact in the database has records of user. Below is my User class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Team;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract
{
  use Authenticatable, Authorizable, SoftDeletes;

  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'users';

  protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

  /**
   * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $guarded = ['created_at','deleted_at','updated_at'];

  /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'is_admin' => 'boolean',
        'is_owner' => 'boolean',
    ];

  /**
   * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  //protected $hidden = ['user_pass'];

  public function getRememberToken()
  {
    return null; // not supported
  }

  public function setRememberToken($value){  }

  public function getRememberTokenName()
  {
    return null; // not supported
  }

  /**
   * Overrides the method to ignore the remember token.
   */
  public function setAttribute($key, $value)
  {
    $isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
    if (!$isRememberTokenAttribute)
    {
      parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
  }
  public function isOwner()
  {
    return ($this->is_owner); 
  }
  public function isAdminOrOwner()
  {
    return ($this->is_admin || $this->is_owner);
  }
}
```

[here is the result of vardump(App\User::all()) and dd(App\User::all())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMLJH.png)

After checking my database i found out that the users table column `deleted_at` has default value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` which make the SoftDeletes from Laravel considered every entry as deleted thus it return NULL/empty

**Fix**:

Made nullable `deleted_at` column.
Set all `deleted_at` timestamps to NULL.

Comment: How do you accessing it to get `null` ? Show it to us ...

Comment: @ihue i'll try $users = App\User::all(); but it return null.... when i try to query using DB::table('users')->get(); it has all the result.

Comment: Try `$users = User::all();`, , and try `dd($users);` if it work let me know.

Comment: I would suggest add `use App\User;` to the top of your controller.

Comment: @ihue i already had. but still no luck